How can I use WhenEvent to make one object (follower) follow another obect (mover) with a gap between them?
My problem
I'm trying to implement a program in Mathematica where a "follower" moves with a "mover." Both the mover and the follower move up and down. Specifically:
1. There is a gap of size g between the mover and the follower.
2. They move together only when the mover touches the upper or lower boundary of the follower.
3. When the mover changes direction, they separate, and the follower stops.
4. Although @Daniel Huber provided a result that I was looking for, I would still prefer to solve my problem using WhenEvent, as it would make it easier to apply to the more complicated ordinary differential equations I'm actually dealing with. Nevertheless, I am very grateful for his help.
I've drawn a diagram to better illustrate the process. In this diagram, the mover is the blue object and the red one is the follower.
[![mover-follower-with-a-gap][1]][1]
My naive code
I wrote a program, but the results is not correct.
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;
f = 5; T = 1/f; tend = 2 T;

moverfun[t_] := 2 Sin[5 Pi f t^2] + Cos[20 Pi f t^3];

g = 0.8;
sol = NDSolve[{zM''[t] == moverfun''[t],   
  MaxSteps -> Infinity]

Show[{Plot[zF[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tend}], 
  Plot[zM[t] /. sol, {t, 0, tend}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]}, 
 PlotRange -> All]

Variables in the program:
Continuous Variables:

zM: displacement of the mover
zF: displacement of the follower

Discrete Variables:

m: whether the follower is moving
rTop, zrTop: whether the
mover changes direction at the top and its displacement at that time
rBot, zrBot: whether the mover changes direction at the bottom
and its displacement at that time


It is easier to calculate first the mover alone without When-events:
mover[t_] = 
 zM[t] /. 
  NDSolve[{zM''[t] == moverfun''[t], zM'[0] == zM[0] == 0, 
     zrTop[0] == g, m[0] == 1}, {zM}, {t, 0, tend}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity][[1]]
Plot[mover[t], {t, 0, tend}]


To get the follower, we need a function with a memory because its value depends on the last seen point:
mem=0;    
getf[{x_, y_}] := Module[{g = 0.8},
  {x, Which[0 <= mem - y <= g, mem,
    mem < y, mem = y,
    mem - g > y, mem = y + g]
   }
  ]

Now we need to apply this to the mover data from left to right. Towards this aim, we discretize t:
datm = Table[{t, mover[t]}, {t, 0, tend, tend/100}];
datf = funf /@ datm;

Now we have the data to define the follower:
follower[t_] = Interpolation[datf][t]
Plot[{mover[t], follower[t]}, {t, 0, tend}]



Thank you very much for your response. However, I apologize for not being clear: this question is a simplified version of a problem I encountered in practice. In my actual problem, the displacement of the mover is not known in advance and is also a variable to be solved for. If that’s the case, would the method you provided still be applicable?

If g is variable, define it as a function of t outside of getf.

Thanks, g is a constant. But the displacement of the mover needs to be solved using NDSolve; it is not given in advance and is even coupled with the displacement of the follower. NDSolve needs to solve for the displacements of both the mover and the follower simultaneously.

I do not understand. The follower is depended on the mover, but the mover is not depended on the follower. Therefore, the mover can be solved first as I did above.

Thank you very much. Actually, what I prefer is to implement it using WhenEvent, but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. I think I need some time to think this over carefully.
